# On the html page there are large of white spaces and I am not able to cut them

Tags: html, css

```css
    
    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* remove default 8px margin from body */
    body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    /* No need for this
    #main_page {
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    */
    .cuisines_about {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 450px;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .cuisines_description {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .cuisines_description h2 {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 300px;
        font-size: 80px;
    }

    .cuisines_images {
        /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
        width: 100%;
        /*height: 500px;*/
        display: flex;
        /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    }

    .cusines_images img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    }

    .cuisines_16pic {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    .cuisines_9pic {
        flex: 2 2 auto;
    }
    #homepage nav{
        background-color:lightskyblue;
    }
    #footer { 
        position: fixed; 
        padding: 10px 10px 0 10px; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 100%; 
    } 
    .copyright_info{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs_selector ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    .form-inline{
        padding-left:50px;
        padding-right:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="homepage">
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand"><a class="nav-link" href="#homepage">
                <img src="ufood.png" alt="ufood logo" width="50" height="50">
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="foodDelivery_about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Mission">Mission</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#foodMenu">Menu</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#Chinese">Chinese</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#Japanese">Japanese</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#Italian">Italian</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#German">German</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#French">French</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#Spanish">Spanish</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#American">American</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#shopBranches">Branches</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hong Kong Island</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kowloon</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New Territories</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Browse by cuisines">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="main_page">
            <div class="cuisines_about">
              <div class="cuisines_description">
                <h2>Enjoy different cuisines <br> around the world!</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="cuisines_images">
                <img class="cuisines_16pic" src="different_cuisines.png" alt="image of food" width="700" height="450">
                <img class="cuisines_9pic" src="different_cuisines02.png" width="550" height="450" alt="Image of food">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
<p class="copyright_info">Copyright © 2021 Sham Tseng Restaurant. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Although I tried editing a few times with the margin the green box still cannot be put on the leftmost of the page without white spaces. After I edited my code the contents are still put on the middle rather than on the leftmost. The result that I want is to align the green box and two images on the same row and the images to be put on the right of the green box without any spaces.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5YpY.jpg): [image: Screenshot of the html page]

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you are looking to do, but this is always a good rule to add to your CSS and helps eliminate that white space on the edges `* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}`

Comment: What exactly are you looking to change? The white space above the green container or the white space on each side of the green container caused by the `margin: 8px` default style on the `<body>`?

Comment: why are you giving 100% width to description when you want to save space for cuisine_image

Comment: I used ```.container-fluid``` then the solution is fixed